# Are there Ruby servers that can handle multiple requests in one thread?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, thin

coming from Java world where we have NIO (nonblocking IO) I am not able to find a Ruby server that would be able to do the same as Jetty for example - to handle multiple requests with one thread. This is application transparent and using multiple threads / multiple processes, servers can handle thousands of concurrent requests easily.

I have only seen some application level "hacks" with EventMachine using deffer and other methods to handle more requests, but I think there could be servers doing that for applications translarently. Also Ruby 1.9 have now Fibers, so it could also leverage that. I just do not want to rebuild my application to scale up.

Is there something like that?

Comment: Are you talking about web servers?  What servers have you tried?  What were the shortcomings of those servers for your application?

Answer (score 1):

How about Unicorn? http://unicorn.bogomips.org It's multi-process, not multi-thread